# Django Python Creating Object inside Model delete function returns 500 Error

Tags: python, django, rest

I am trying to create a new Entry of CloudProfileTransaction before deleting a record.
When saving a new record the exact same code works fine ( with: super().save(*args, **kwargs)).

If I remove the CloudProfileTransaction code the deletion works.

the following code throws a Response 500 Error.
what am I missing?

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        CloudProfileTransaction.objects.create(
            cloud_giver = self.follower,
            cloud_receiver = self.followee,
            cloud_model = CloudModel.objects.get(investment='Follow'),
            add = False
        )
        
    
        Followers.objects.filter(user=self.follower).update(followers=F('followers')-1)
        Followees.objects.filter(user=self.followee).update(followees=F('followees')-1)

        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Error Message: E/Volley: [28490] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 500

Comment: Please include the entire traceback as it's hard to diagnose the issue. Also, you should probably use [django model signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/) to do this.

Comment: @rob, thanx for the feedback. I identified the issue. you were right. With the above code it was impossible to identify (completely unrelated). I am implementing signals now, looks like the right way to go